# How the weight of an object lighter than water changes if it is pushed and tied to bottom, going upwards and floating on the surface?

Tags: water, buoyancy

Imagine I push an object to the bottom of water with a rope (through a ring at the bottom) and attach the rope to the top of container. If I cut the rope the object will go upwards.

1. will there be differences at the weight of the container when the object was attached to the bottom, going upwards and finally at the surface
2. How can I calculate the speed of an object going from bottom to the top? Let’s say its density is 800kg/m3
3. Will there be any acceleration as it goes upwards?
4. Will the shape of object affect the speed of movement?

Comment: A figure would be immensely helpful, and I think there is a mistake in your description.  Do you mean tying an object that would normally float, to the *bottom* of the tank? Also this is a very interesting exercise for you to think through yourself.  A hint is, draw a free body diagram with $\Sigma F = ma$ for the object at each stage.

Comment: Yes I mean tying an object that would normally float to the bottom of the tank. 
Let’s say 8 kg mass with 800kg/m3 density.